# Mozilla FireFox page controls changing based on authentication type

Tags: css, .net, html, firefox

I have a .NET MVC web page that contains 3 radio buttons for choosing a value on a form. In a certain test environment that offers two methods of authentication (user/pass or certificate), the radio buttons will change to checkboxes when the page is loaded. This appears to happen when using the user/pass method, but not the certificate.

Browser version is FireFox 52.3 in the environment where this is being tested.

Need to check if it is using a moz-appearance style, but I don't think so.

I suspect that it might have to do with security zones, based on the differing behavior between authentication types.

Has anyone experienced this type of behavior before? Suggestions for what to try?

Comment: No ideas anyone?  Note that it is NOT using the moz-appearance style, so that's out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work-around for this issue.  We are using Bootstrap styles in our site. At first we thought that utilizing the **.disabled** class was causing the problem, but removing this class and using the disabled attribute instead did not solve the problem.

After much playing around, I stumbled upon an abnormality with the line-height in the body element declared in the Bootstrap.css.  Its default value was 1.428571429.  In the FF Inspector, I experimented by changing the value from 1.3 to 1.6 and variants in between.

For whatever reason, using a value between 1.4 and 1.5 caused the control to change from a radio button to a checkbox. I have no explanation for this, except that it might be a bug, or an interaction from another style.